# Ripping WMTS for serving over CDN

Tags: software-recommendations, wmts

I'm currently running an application using Norwegian and Swedish basemaps, served by the respective government agencies via WMTS, but licensed under variants of Creative Commons. However, I'm not impressed by the latency and robustness of their solution. The Swedish map is slow in Norway and vice versa, and I can't even fathom how it looks over a trans-atlantic connection.

I'd like to copy the tiles of the relevant areas from the respective WMTS services and serving them myself over a CDN. Are there any industry standard tools for ripping the tiles of a WMTS or will I have to write my own script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into MapProxy, see https://mapproxy.org/

This will not rip all tiles, but cache the requested tiles. I think this is far nicer on the source services (which also might have provisions against mass downloading of all their data).

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. The seed functionality for pre-loading tiles looks spot on for my use case.